# WebSocket onmessage connection is null React-ReduxSaga

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket, redux-saga

I am getting a null `.onmessage`
but .onopen is working

```
import * as types from './types';
import { eventChannel } from 'redux-saga';
import { takeEvery, put, call, select, take } from 'redux-saga/effects';


export function* createEventChannel() {
  const mySocket = new WebSocket('wss://url.com');
  return eventChannel((emit: any) => {
    mySocket.onopen = () => {
      mySocket.send("sdsdsdsd!");
    };
// =====> onmessage is getting null
    mySocket.onmessage((message:any) => {
        emit(message.data)
    });

    return () => {
      mySocket.close();
    };
    
  });
}

export function* workWebSocket(action:any) {
  const channel = yield call(createEventChannel);
  while (true) {
    const { message } = yield take(channel);
    yield put({ type: types.WEB_SOCKET_SUCCESS, message: message });
  }
}

export default function* watchHydration() {
  yield takeEvery(types.WEB_SOCKET_FETCH, workWebSocket);
}
```

Any suggestions on why I am getting null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this example: could you parse the data properly?

```
function initWebsocket() {
return eventChannel(emitter => {
ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl + '/client')
ws.onopen = () => {
  console.log('opening...')
  ws.send('hello server')
}
ws.onerror = (error) => {
  console.log('WebSocket error ' + error)
  console.dir(error)
}
ws.onmessage = (e) => {
  let msg = null
  try {
    msg = JSON.parse(e.data)
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(`Error parsing : ${e.data}`)
  }
  if (msg) {
    const { payload: book } = msg
    const channel = msg.channel
    switch (channel) {
      case 'ADD_BOOK':
        return emitter({ type: ADD_BOOK, book })
      case 'REMOVE_BOOK':
        return emitter({ type: REMOVE_BOOK, book })
      default:
        // nothing to do
    }
  }
}
// unsubscribe function
return () => {
  console.log('Socket off')
 }
})
}
export default function* wsSagas() {
const channel = yield call(initWebsocket)
 while (true) {
  const action = yield take(channel)
  yield put(action)
}
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I did parse the data correctly. But  I figure out I made a mistake on arrow function onMessage
`// =====> This is where I made a mistake 
    mySocket.onmessage = function ((message:any) => {
        emit(message.data)
    });`

Comment: I'm glad that was helpful. and I spotted the ```mySocket.onmessage``` as well